# ffmpeg undefined symbol: mpg123_param2 on

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system and ffmpeg does not run:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0: undefined symbol: mpg123_param2
```

I have the following installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mpg
ii  libmpg123-0:amd64                          1.29.3-1build1                          amd64        MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder (shared library)
ii  mpg123
```

I also have another system that has been upgraded many times where ffmpeg works. It has the same version of libmpg123 and I compared the checksum on the libmpg123.so.0.46.7 on both systems and they match.

I have tried removing ffmpeg and the dependencies that were no longer needed, then reinstalling, but it made no difference.

Is there another library I need to install?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks for your time.
Chris

Comment: Please post the following command output : `ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep libopenmpt` . If you find no link install the lib  with `sudo apt install libopenmpt0`   . Otherwise run `ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg ` and look for not installed libs.

Comment: Did you installed the libmpg123 ?

Comment: $ ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep libopenmpt
        libopenmpt.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0 (0x00007fafa8c51000)

ldd shows no missing libraries.

$ dpkg -l libmpg123-0
||/ Name              Version        Architecture Description
+++-=================-==============-============-===============================================
ii  libmpg123-0:amd64 1.29.3-1build1 amd64        MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder (shared library)

Comment: `$ ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep libopenmpt`

`libopenmpt.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0 (0x00007fafa8c51000)`

ldd shows no missing libraries.

`$ dpkg -l libmpg123-0`

`||/ Name              Version        Architecture Description`
`+++-=================-==============-============-===============================================`

`ii  libmpg123-0:amd64 1.29.3-1build1 amd64        MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder (shared library)`

Comment: `whereis ffmpeg` please

Comment: Do you have a locally compiled library of libopenmpt ? Maybe you can try `sudo apt install --reinstall libopenmpt0`   . Maybe a `sudo ldconfig` does the job ?

Comment: Sometimes you have to reinstall ffmepg. But first clean your apt cache (this will delete all locally apt packages in the /var/cache/apt/archives ) - which is safe `sudo apt clean` . Uninstall ffmpeg with `sudo remove ffmpeg libopenmpt0` and try to install it again with `sudo install ffmpeg` .

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I still see the same problem. I also noticed that mpg123 won't run, giving this error `mpg123: symbol lookup error: mpg123: undefined symbol: mpg123_par2` ldd does not show any missing libs for mpg123

Comment: Looks like they didn't updated the libopenmpt0. You can compile it by source or make a  bug report. I think the problem is that they forgot to link the correct library This is very strange in my opinion. Bug report: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg

Comment: `which ffmpeg` or `whereis ffmpeg` shows you the path which should be /usr/bin/ffmpeg`